# sending multiple sms using SMSLib within same process

Tags: java, sms, port, smslib

I am using SMSLib to send sms using my samsung gsm modem.
I created a seperate thread that gets the messages from server in every 20 seconds
and if it gets the message it calls the SendMessage..  here is the code for SendMessage

```
public class SendMessage {
public boolean doIt(String num, String umsg) {

    try {
        OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
        System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
        System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
        System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
        SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com10","COM10", 115200, "Samsung", "");
        gateway.setInbound(true);
        gateway.setOutbound(true);
        gateway.setSimPin("0000");

        gateway.setSmscNumber("+919826012311");
        Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
        Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
        Service.getInstance().startService();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Modem Information:");
        System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
        System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
        System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
        System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
        System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel()+ " dBm");
        System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel()+ "%");
        System.out.println();

        OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(num, umsg);
        Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

        System.out.println(msg);

        Service.getInstance().stopService();
        gateway.stopGateway();

        return true;
    } catch (GatewayException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SMSLibException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            Service.getInstance().stopService();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GatewayException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SMSLibException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification {
    public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg) {
        System.out.println("Outbound handler called from Gateway: "
                + gateway.getGatewayId());
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}

}
```

This code is working great for the first time i call doIt. but If my thread gets more sms
from server and then if i call doIt , it throws an exception

> org.smslib.GatewayException: Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.comm.PortInUseException: Port currently owned by org.smslib
>   at org.smslib.modem.SerialModemDriver.connectPort(SerialModemDriver.java:102)
>   at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:114)
>   at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
>   at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:275)

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not closing down SmsLib correctly as the exception seems to implicate that the connection to the serial port is left open.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me. Use

```
Service.getInstance().sendMessages(myList, gateway.getGatewayId());
```

function instead of using sendmessage mylist.add(msg);

`mylist` is list containing outboung msg